# Understanding segments in Bernstein-Zelevinsky Classification

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, classification, admissible-representation

All reps shall be admissible in what follows.

Let $k$ be a non-arch. field, $n = a\cdot b$ natural numbers and $P = M \cdot N \subset \mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ the standard parabolic subgroup with
$$
M = \mathrm{GL}_a(k) \times \ldots \times \mathrm{GL}_a(k). \qquad(b \text{ times})
$$
I have a question concerning *segments*: Prasad-Raghuram ([https://www.math.tifr.res.in/~dprasad/ictp2.pdf](https://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Edprasad/ictp2.pdf)) define them as follows:

If $\sigma$ is a cusp.irr.representation of $\mathrm{GL}_a(k)$, then the **segment** $\Delta$ of $\sigma$ is the representation
$$
\Delta = \sigma \otimes \sigma | \hspace{1pt} \cdot  \hspace{1pt} | \otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma | \hspace{1pt} \cdot  \hspace{1pt} |^{b-1}
$$
of $M$ (see below Thm. 7.4. in *loc.cit.*). Then in Chapter 8 (Langlands Classification) they define the relation *linked* on segments:

Given segments $\Delta = \sigma \otimes \sigma | \hspace{1pt} \cdot  \hspace{1pt} | \otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma | \hspace{1pt} \cdot  \hspace{1pt} |^{b-1}$ and $\Delta' = \sigma' \otimes \sigma' | \hspace{1pt} \cdot  \hspace{1pt} | \otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma' | \hspace{1pt} \cdot  \hspace{1pt} |^{b-1}$, we say they are *linked*, if

- $\Delta \not\subset \Delta'$ and $\Delta' \not\subset \Delta$
- $\Delta \cup \Delta'$ is a segment.

**My question is:** How should I understand it?

**My attempt:** I kind of 'understand' the first condition as: the reps should not be embeddable into each other in the sense that for example; if I have $\sigma$ an irr.cusp.rep. of $\mathrm{GL}_2(k)$ and $\sigma'$ an irr.cusp.rep. of $\mathrm{GL}_1(k) = k^{\times}$, then it could happen that $\sigma$ is, as a representation of $\mathrm{GL}_1(k) \times \mathrm{GL}_1(k)$, reducible, and has a subrepresentation isomorphic to $\sigma' \otimes \sigma' | \hspace{1pt} \cdot  \hspace{1pt} |$.

For the second, the 'union' of representations makes no sense, so I would assume, if I tensor the two segments (as $\Delta \otimes \Delta'$ or as $\Delta' \otimes \Delta$), then I should get a segment of $\mathrm{GL}_{2n}(k)$ of the form
$$
\Delta \otimes \Delta' = \sigma \otimes \sigma | \hspace{1pt} \cdot  \hspace{1pt} | \otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma | \hspace{1pt} \cdot  \hspace{1pt} |^{b+b'-1},
$$
so basically $\Delta' = \Delta| \hspace{1pt} \cdot  \hspace{1pt} |^b$. What I also kind of imagine is that one can also talk about linked segments of not necessarily the same 'size': $\Delta$ could be of size $n = ab$ and $\Delta'$ of size $n' = a'b'$. If they are linked (thus $\Delta \cup \Delta'$ is a segment), this would imply $a = a'$, but I could still have $b \neq b'$.

Bernstein-Zelevinsky define segments by partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into set of consecutive numbers which makes much more sense for me.

Does it make sense what I wrote or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: Segments should be defined as sets of the form $\{\rho,\nu\rho,\dots,\nu^{b-1}\rho\}$, and we can attach a representation $\rho\otimes\cdots\otimes\nu^{b-1}\rho$ to such a set. Bernstein-Zelevinsky's definition is the correct one.